# How to upgrade to PostgreSQL 11 for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

As the title suggests I want to upgrade my `postgresql-10` to `postgresql-11`.

I'm using `ubuntu-18.04`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can follow this blog [setup Postgresql-11 on Ubuntu](https://linuxhint.com/setup_postgresql_replication/). I found it easy and simple.

Add the PostgreSQL package repository on your Ubuntu machine

```
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main 11" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgsql.list
```

Add the GPG key of the PostgreSQL package repository:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Update APT and install postgresql-11

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install postgresql-11
```

Comment: Getting Invalid operation postgresql-11

Comment: doesn't this just install a second instance that will run alongside the first?

Comment: @dangel it will. I followed this tutorial on how to remove the first: https://www.paulox.net/2019/05/28/upgrading-postgresql-from-version-10-to-11-on-ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo/

Comment: This solution is not for Ubuntu 18.04 since postgresql-11 is not part of the 18.04 repository

Answer (score 13):

Upgrading Postgres to the latest version (currently 13), or to an intermediate version such as 11, should be done by running:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-common
sudo sh /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.sh
```

This is documented on https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt
This runs a bash script on your computer. See there if you wish to run the steps manually.

Once you have installed Postgres, the easiest way to upgrade on Ubuntu is with [pg_upgradecluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pg_upgradecluster.8.html).

1. Backup your data. You will dropping the database, so no games!

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall > all.sql
```

2. Upgrade.

```
// Install latest Postgres. Use `postgresql-11` for v11 instead of `postgresql` for latest.   
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql
    
// The install sets up a cluster, which needs then to be removed for the upgrade. 
// Stop and remove the newly installed cluster. Use `11` instead of `13` for v11
sudo pg_dropcluster 13 main --stop
    
// Upgrade the db. Takes the OLD version and OLD schema as required arguments
sudo pg_upgradecluster 10 main
    
// Test. Once you are satisfied, remove OLD cluster.
sudo pg_dropcluster 10 main
```

Comment: Very useful reply! I missed installing some extensions (postgis) of the new version and had many errors in upgrade. Installing the extension package, then running dropcluster followed by upgradecluster again fixed it!

Answer (score -2):

Use this command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install postgresql-11
```

Comment: postgresql-11 is not part of the 18.04 repository