# How to upgrade postgresql inside a Kubernetes pod?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster running an app. Part of the cluster is a postgresql pod, currently running version 10.4. Unfortunately, I discovered that I need to upgrade the postgresql version.

The postgres yaml is as follow:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:10.4
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

The postgresql database already has some data in it. I need to find a way to upgrade the cluster while in production.

If I simply try to change the image to 12.0 and run `kubectl apply` I get an error:

```
2020-11-15 22:48:08.332 UTC [1] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 10, which is not compatible with this version 12.5 (Debian 12.5-1.pgdg100+1).
```

So I understand that I need to manually upgrade the postgres database inside the cluster, and only then I will be able to fix the yaml. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi there. You should probably look for the "approved upgrade path" for Pg 10 --> 12. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409585/how-to-upgrade-postgresql-database-from-10-to-12-without-losing-data-for-openpro

Make sure you've backed up the data before making any changes.

Answer (score 6):

I tried @Justin method, but I encountered an issue that I couldn't stop current running postgres process inside the pod (for some reason inside the container there is no access to postgresql service. You can see more about that issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64855485/how-do-i-stop-postgresql-server-inside-container/64857097#64857097))

Since I couldn't upgrade the postgresql specifically inside the pod, what I did at the end is creating a parallel postgres pod in Kubernetes which holds the new version. Then I dumped database from old server, copied it to the new server, and used it to initialize the database there.

Here are the steps one by one:

1. Create a parallel postgres service with the new version
2. In old version pod:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgresadmin -h localhost -p 5432 > dumpall.sql
```

3. In the host:

```
kubectl cp postgres-old-pod:/dumpall.sql dumpall.sql
kubectl cp dumpall.sql postgres2-new-pod:/dumpall.sql
```

4. ssh to new-pod
5. extra step that I needed, becuase for some reason new pod didn't had 'postgres' user created:
   get into postgres client using your credentials:

```
psql postgresql://postgresadmin:pass1234@127.0.0.1:5432/postgresdb?sslmode=disable
postgresdb=# CREATE ROLE postgres LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'somepassword123';
```

then exit postgres and exit to normal user

6. Finally update the database:

```
psql -U postgres -W -f dumpall.sql
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for k8s yml automation?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @justadev for the answer. Some additions:

```
psql -U postgres -d keycloak -W -f dumpall.sql
```

I had to add the `-d keycloak` database flag because while the `psql` log was OK during the import, the data was missing in the database afterwards. You need to explicitly indicate the database for `psql`.

So, check the `psql` flags here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

By the way, I managed to upgrade from Postgres 11 to Posgres 14.5 this way.

Also, I want to add this:
`tar` may be absent on a pod, this means that `kubectl cp` will not work.

Here is the workaround:

1. Copy data from a pod to a local machine:

```
kubectl exec -n ${namespace} ${postgresql_pod} -- cat db_dump.sql  > db_dump.sql
```

2. Copy data from a local machine to a pod:

```
cat db_dump.sql | kubectl exec -i -n ${namespace} ${postgresql_pod} "--" sh -c "cat > db_dump.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this [How to upgrade postgresql database from 10 to 12 without losing data for openproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409585/how-to-upgrade-postgresql-database-from-10-to-12-without-losing-data-for-openpro) as the basis for my post. I'm converting it to a container-with-volume friendly approach. I am assuming you're using the official Postgresql image on Docker Hub.

1. Backup the data - Out of scope for this answer. There are other people better suited to answering that question.
2. Upgrade postgres from inside the pod and migrate the data
   Get a shell in your postgres pod

```sh
# insert your pod and namespace here
kubectl exec -it postgresl-shsdjkfshd -n default /bin/sh
```

Run the following inside the container

```sh
apt update
apt-get install postgresql-12 postgresql-server-dev-12
service postgresql stop
# Migrate the data
su postgres
/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_upgrade \
     --old-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/10/main \
     --new-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/12/main \
     --old-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin \
     --new-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin \
     --old-options '-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf' \
     --new-options '-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf'
exit # exits the postgres user
```

The next bit is verbatim taken from the linked post:

3. Swap the ports the old and new postgres versions.

```
     vim /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
     #change port to 5432
     vim /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
     #change port to 5433
```

4. Start the postgresql service

```
     service postgresql start
```

5. Log in as postgres user

```
     su postgres
```

6. Check your new postgres version

```
     psql -c "SELECT version();"
```

7. Run the generated new cluster script

```
     ./analyze_new_cluster.sh
```

8. Return as a normal(default user) user and cleanup up the old version's mess

```
     apt-get remove postgresql-10 postgresql-server-dev-10
     #uninstalls postgres packages
     rm -rf /etc/postgresql/10/
     #removes the old postgresql directory
     su postgres
     #login as postgres user
     ./delete_old_cluster.sh
     #delete the old cluster data
```

9. Now change the deployment YAML image reference to the Postgres 12 and `kubectl apply`
10. Check the logs to see if it started up correctly.

Comment: "the following inside the container" --- it's not possible

Comment: You cannot `service postgresql stop` inside container.

Comment: Hi there. I asked on Github and they pointed me to this conversation https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/37