# How to resolve postgresql upgrade permission denied in ubuntu focal wsl?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm just not understanding how it can be so difficult to upgrade a program on a Linux distro. I am having the most difficult time upgrading from PostgreSQL-12 to PostgreSQL-16.
My current distro is **Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)** in Windows Subsystem for Linux.
I have been following steps from this source: [how to upgrade postgresql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409585/how-to-upgrade-postgresql-database-from-10-to-12-without-losing-data-for-openpro)

I'm stuck at step 3.

```
    /usr/lib/postgresql/16/bin/pg_upgrade \
--old-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/12/main \
--new-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/16/main \
--old-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin \
--new-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/16/bin \
--old-options '-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf' \
--new-options '-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf'
```

Running this command results in the following error:

```
could not create directory "/var/lib/postgresql/16/main/pg_upgrade_output.d": Permission denied
Failure, exiting
```

Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try sudo?

Comment: Run the command as a user that has the permissions.

Comment: yes, I tried sudo.  You cannot run this command from root.

Comment: Laurenz, my current user profile should have full access.

Answer (score 1):

I initially didn't know much about Ubuntu and default server applications that are included with each version of this Linux distribution. I still don't know a lot, but I know more now.

Each Ubuntu version has a pre-installed version of PostgreSQL database server application. My current version of Ubuntu is 20.04.6 LTS Focal Fossa which comes with PostgreSQL-12.  When I want to run a database session of this server application, I connect to it via localhost on port 5432.  This is achieved by using the command / service manager *sudo service PostgreSQL start* among other methods.

This starts the server on the default port 5432 as mentioned.  I can enter a PostgreSQL database by using the command *psql* assuming that my current user profile also has a defined postgresql role and database of the same name.

Of course, over time, there may come the need to use a functionality that is not present in Postgresql-12. This might require that I install a more recent / major version of PostgreSQL. To date, the latest version of PostgreSQL is version 16.  Since version 16 is what was pulled from the repository downloaded from a wget request that I made, version 16 is what I decided to use.

I used the commands *sudo apt update* and then *sudo apt upgrade postgresql-16* which installed version 16 alongside version 12.  Ubuntu has packages that allow multiple versions of PostgreSQL to run together.  I assumed that after installing version 16 it would upgrade to version 12 resulting in only one version, the most recent version 16, but, as mentioned, Ubuntu doesn't do this, and for good reason: Data is very sensitive, and things can go wrong. Leave the previous installation alone and create a separate instance to isolate concerns. This makes sense to me now, but frustrated me initially because I needed to connect to the postgresql-16 server to use postgresql-client-16 features.

Which raises a new question for a noob like me, "How do I get my databases in version 12 to exist in version 16 :( XD?"

The solution is to use pg_dump to backup the databases in version 12 using the command

*pg_dumpall > outputfilehere*

For example,

*pg_dumpall > alldatabases.dump*

or, if I want to target a specific database and not all of them then I could use

*pg_dump > my_specific_database.dump*

Before I can "restore" my databases to the latest version I installed alongside version 12, I have to switch ports.  Version 16 is located on port 5433 because version 12 occupies port 5432, which is the default port.  I have to switch the port numbers. This is achieved by making changes in the server application configuration or settings file for each version.

in Ubuntu and other Linux distributions, server application configuration files (generally a file with a *.config* extension) are located in the */etc* directory. Here are the config file locations for each version:

*/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf*

*/etc/postgresql/16/main/postgresql.conf*

I can change to the version 12 config directory using the command

*cd /etc/postgresql/12/main*

Now that I am in the main directory, I can type the command

*ls -la*

to see that there is a file named postgresql.conf. I can change the port number in this file by using a text editor like nano or vim.  I used vim by typing the following command:

*sudo vim postgresql.conf*

*make sure to include *sudo* because you need superuser permissions to write to/edit server application config files. This will open the file in the vim editor where I can see that the current port number is 5432.  I changed the port to 5433.  I then followed the same steps to change the port in /etc/postgresql/16/main from 5433 to 5432.

ALMOST THERE.  Installation of a more recent version of PostgreSQL creates the user postgres, so in order to make changes to databases you will have to login as user postgres in Ubuntu by switching users (su):

*su - postgres*

or

*sudo -i -u postgres*

either way, start the PostgreSQL service using:

*sudo service PostgreSQL start*

(you may be able to omit sudo)

This will start both version 16 and version 12 servers, but if you want to start a specific server, then simply add the version you want to start at the end of the command:

*sudo service PostgreSQL start 16*

if you want to stop a specific version:

*sudo service PostgreSQL stop 16*

Finally, type the command *psql*
You will enter the postgres database.
Then type

*CREATE USER your_desired_ubuntu_username_here WITH LOGIN CREATEDB CREATEROLE SUPERUSER*

*you may or may not want to add superuser permissions, your choice.

now type *exit* to leave the database

finally, switch users back to the original user:

*su - your_ubuntu_username_here*

Lastly type the command createddb your_ubuntu_username here.

create another database to restore your backups:

*creatdb database_name_here*

FINALLY READY TO MOVE VERSION 12 DATABASES TO VERSION 16:

Type the command *psql database_name_here < backupfile_here*

check that the move was a success by entering the database:

Type *psql*

then type *\c database_name_here*

then type *\d to view relations*

If you see the number of rows expected, then it was a success.