# How to change postgresql version on Ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

How to change postgresql version on Ubuntu?
I am currently running 10.12 but I wanna switch to a new one. How to do it?

Comment: You must add a postgresql repository in a pgdg.list file in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder, then update, then search and choose a new server or postgres utility

Comment: It's depends on Ubuntu version you have.  For example guide for Ubuntu 19 https://www.paulox.net/2019/05/28/upgrading-postgresql-from-version-10-to-11-on-ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade to PostgreSQL 11 for Ubuntu 18.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765873/how-to-upgrade-to-postgresql-11-for-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Do you want to preserve the existing data?